# Azure DevOps branch policies based on target branch name

Tags: azure-devops, git-branch

I'm trying to create a separated branch policy (allow skip build) for PRs that have a specific naming pattern for their **target** branch (which is not master).

It can’t be applied after the PR is created, as I want it to automatically set for all future PRs in this pattern.

Can it be done via some UI or API calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create your pattern with `/`, for example: `hotfix/test`, `hotfix/test2`, now ADO will create a "folder":

[image]

Now you can put branch policies on the folder:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is a condition about the src branch, not the target, right? I'm missing where I can activate the policy where the target branch is hotfix/*

Comment: @DanaSagiAdir It's for the **target** branch, not for the source.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there any solution that involves the src branch as well?

Comment: No, the Branch Policies it's always for the target branches.